# How to we customise a sorting function based on the first alphabet of the word in a list?

Tags: python

Write a function that takes in a list of strings and return a list with the strings in sorted
order, except group all the strings that begin with 'H' first.
For example, providing the following input list:

```
['Bougainvillea', 'Orchids', 'Hibiscus', 'Frangipani', 'Honeysuckle']
```

will return the following output list:

```
['Hibiscus', 'Honeysuckle', 'Bougainvillea', 'Frangipani', 'Orchids']
```

Comment: Where is your attempt of solving this and what went wrong?

Comment: The simplest way to approach this is to pull the ones starting with `h` out first and sort then into a new list, then sort the rest (with the `h` entries removed) and extend that new list with the sorted results of the non `h` containing list.  You can construct a sort comparator that does it all at once but it probably is not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a `key` function to specify sorting order. For example, you can do this:

```py
>>> the_list = ['Bougainvillea', 'Orchids', 'Hibiscus', 'Frangipani', 'Honeysuckle']
>>> sorted(the_list, key=lambda item: (0 if item.startswith("H") else 1, item))
['Hibiscus', 'Honeysuckle', 'Bougainvillea', 'Frangipani', 'Orchids']
```

Your `key` function can produce anything that’s sortable. This example used a tuple, and tuples are sorted elementwise (ties in `the_tuple[0]` are broken by `the_tuple[1]` and so on)

Comment: Haii is it possible if you could explain using pycharm maybe? im really a beginner haha

Comment: @Anonymous_learner what do you mean? Pycharm is an IDE. It is just a place where you write the code. The code is the same...